# Python: graph not being plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib

My issue is that I am trying to create a graph using matplotlib.pyplot to plot the maximum deflection and position of this max deflection, calculated by another function, for a list of 'person' objects which contain the information required to create load tuples to input into the function.

My current code is shown below.

Part 1 beamModel.py (which is working perfectly):

```
import scipy.misc
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy

class beam(object):
    '''This class is models the deflection of a simply supported beam under
    multiple point loads, following Euler-Bernoulli theory and the principle of
    superposition
    '''


    def __init__(self, E, I, L):
        '''The class costructor
        '''
        self.E = E  # Young's modulus of the beam in N/m^2
        self.I = I  # Second moment of area of the beam in m^4
        self.L = L  # Length of the beam in m
        self.Loads = [(0.0, 0.0)]  # the list of loads applied to the beam

    def setLoads(self, Loads):
        '''This function allows multiple point loads to be applied to the beam
        using a list of tuples of the form (load, position)
        '''
        self.Loads = Loads

    def beamDeflection(self, Load, x):
        """Calculate the deflection at point x due to application of single
        load
        """
        Force, distanceA = Load  #P1 = Force , a = distanceA
        E = self.E
        I = self.I
        L = self.L
        distanceB = L - distanceA
        i = (Force*distanceB)/(6*L*E*I)
        j = ((L/distanceB)*(x-distanceA)**3 - x**3 + (L**2 - distanceB**2)*x)
        k = (Force*distanceB*x)/(6*L*E*I)        
        l = (L**2 - x**2 - distanceB**2)
        if x > distanceA:
            return i*j
        else:
            return k*l


    def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
        """Calculate total deflection of beam due to multiple loads
        """
        #return sum(self.beamDeflection(loadall, x) for loadall in self.Loads)
        return sum(self.beamDeflection(load, x) for load in self.Loads)


    def getMaxDeflection(self):
        """Return a two element tuple containing maximum value of deflection
        and position of maximum deflection
        """
        def D1(x): return self.getTotalDeflection(x)
        D2 = scipy.optimize.fmin(lambda x: -D1(x), 0, full_output = 1, disp = 0)
        return D2[1], D2[0][0]
```

Part 2 personModel.py (which is given and shouldn't be changed):

```
class person(object):
    """This class models the displacement of a person's load as they run at 
    'speed' in one dimension. It assumes that the load is always concentrated 
    in a single point and that the displacement of that point is less than or 
    equal to the displacement of the person's centre of mass. Also the 
    displacement of the load will always be a multiple of 'gait'.
    """
    def __init__(self, arrivalTime, weight, gait, speed):
        """This constructor function defines the person's weight, gait and 
        running speed as well as the time that they arrive at the position of 
        zero displacement.
        """
        self.weight = weight
        self.gait = gait
        self.speed = speed
        self.arrivalTime = arrivalTime

    def loadDisplacement(self, time):
        """This function returns the load and displacement of the person's 
        weight at time 'time', in a tuple: (load,displacement).
        """
        dTime = time - self.arrivalTime
        if dTime < 0 :
            return (0.0,0.0)
        else:
            displacement = self.speed * dTime
            steps = int(displacement/self.gait)
            stepDisplacement = steps*self.gait

            return (9.81*self.weight, stepDisplacement)
```

And part 3 beamSimulation.py (which is giving me issues):

```
import personModel
import beamModel
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot

beam = beamModel.beam

def createPersonList(fileName):
    """Function will go through each line of file and
    create a person object using the data provided in
    the line and add it to a list
    """
    theFile = open(fileName)
    next(theFile)
    for line in theFile:
        aList = line.split(',')
        bList = map(lambda s: s.strip('\n'), aList)
        cList = [float(i) for i in bList]
        return cList


def simulateBeamRun(personList, beam, times):
    """Takes a list of times covering the duration of
    the simulation (0-35 s), the list of person
    objects and a beam object to simulate a beam run
    """
    dList = []
    for time in times:
        eList = []
        personList = []
        for person in personList:
            loadTuples = personModel.person.loadDisplacement(time)
            if beamModel.beam.L > loadTuples[1] > 0:
                eList.append(loadTuples)
            else:
                return None
        beam.setLoads(eList)
        dList.append(beam.getMaxDeflection())
    x = times
    y = []
    z = []
    for i in dList:
        y.append(i[0] * 10**3)
        z.append(i[1])
    matplotlib.pyplot.figure(0)
    matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel("Time (s)")
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y, 'r', label = "Maximum deflection (mm)")
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, z, 'b', label = "Position of maximum deflection (m)")
    matplotlib.pyplot.show
```

An example input for the function `simulateBeamRun` would be:

```
>>> ps = createPersonList('personData.csv')
>>> b = beamModel.beam(8.0E9, 1.333E-4, 5.0)
>>> ts = numpy.linspace(0, 35, 500)
>>> simulateBeamRun(ps, b, ts)
```

However, when I try to run the function, the graph I am given is just a straight line on the x axis (time axis) and so the values of maxDeflection and position of maxDeflection are not being plotted. Help?!

EDIT: The reason is that dList is returning a list of tuples all equal to (0.0, 0.0). I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the values in `dList` are what you expect?  That would help you separate plotting problems from calculation problems.

Comment: Might just be a typo, but you are missing some paranthesis on the end of your second last code block `matplotlib.pyplot.show` should be `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`, though it does not sound like this would cause your error.

Comment: What's in `personData.csv`?

Comment: @cxw I just checked and found that dList is returning a list of tuples all equal to (0.0, 0.0) but cannot figure out why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing *classes* rather than the corresponding *instances*: e.g., `beamModel.beam` directly in places you should be referring to just `beam`.

- At the top of `beamSimulation.py`, remove `beam = beamModel.beam`.
- In `simulateBeamRun`, change `loadTuples = personModel.person.loadDisplacement(time)` to `loadTuples = person.loadDisplacement(time)`.
- In `simulateBeamRun`, change `if beamModel.beam.L > loadTuples[1] > 0:` to `if beam.L > loadTuples[1] > 0:`.

`beamModel.beam` and `personModel.person` are classes you can use to create new instances.  Generally speaking, any reference to either of those (or any `class`) should be followed by parentheses (e.g., `b = beamModel.beam(8.0E9, 1.333E-4, 5.0)`, which is correct).  Once you have an instance (e.g., `b`), just use that and don't refer to `beamModel.beam` any more

By the way, what version of Python are you using?  I'm actually surprised this code runs - I would have expected error messages relating to missing `self` parameters.